# How to make this code algorithm efficient?What the code will be after using this algorithm?How can I avoid time limit exceeded for this program?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have this problem:

Some positive integers can be represented by a sum of one or more consecutive prime numbers. How many such representations does a given positive integer have?

For example, the integer 53 has two representations 5+7+11+13+17 and 53. The integer 41 has three representations 2+3+5+7+11+13, 11 + 13 + 17, and 41. The integer 3 has only one representation, which is 3. The integer 20 has no
such representations.

Note that summands must be consecutive prime numbers, so neither 7 + 13 nor 3 + 5 + 5 + 7 is a valid representation for the integer 20.

The mission is to write a program that reports the number of representations for the given positive integer.

Sample Input:

```
2
3
17
41
20
666
12
53
0
```

Sample Output:

```
1
1
2
3
0
0
1
2
```

I used seive method to get prime number array, p[10011].
My Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, i, j, k, l, sum, count, ara[10011], d[10011];
    while (-1) 
    {
        for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            ara[i] = 0;
        }
        l = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            k = 0;
            scanf("%d", &n);
            int p[n];
            count = 0;
            for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            {
                if (ara[i] == 0) 
                {

                    for (j = 2 * i; j <= n; j += i) 
                    {
                        ara[j] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            {

                if (ara[i] == 0)
                {

                    p[k++] = i;
                }
            }
            for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) 
            {

                if (ara[i] == 0) 
                {

                    p[k++] = i;
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < k; i++) 
            {
                sum = 0;
                for (j = i; j < k; j++) 
                {
                    sum += p[j];
                    if (sum == n) 
                    {
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            d[l] = count;
            if (n == 0)
                break;
            l++;
        }
           for (i = 0; i < l; i++) 
           {
            printf("%d\n", d[i] / 2);
           }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by fixing the indentation.

Comment: @machine_1 my code posting method is wrong, I think.I am new in this community.

Comment: `for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)` looks very odd with an uninitialized `n`. It seems that your program does not even give the right answers. Before you start optimizing, you should write a working program.

Comment: Dynamic programming might be useful here. I do not know if and how your code works because there are zero comments and many one-letter variables. Also this is not a code-writing service, please state what exactly is the problem and what you have done - pseudo code of your algorithm would be useful.  Not that this is not code-writing service, no one here should solve your homework for you.

Comment: @mch I executed this program and I get right output when I give sample input.

Comment: @MdTahmidArefin You say you get the right output... ok, so what is the problem?

Comment: @Quimbyn I will be more concious during giving my next post.Sorry.

Comment: @4386427 Time limit exceeded, when I submit this code.

Comment: What are the limits for number of integers we need to count representations for and maximum value for some integer ?

Comment: If you need to ask a homework question, please read [recommendations for homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) first: "How do I make this better?" isn't the kind of question StackOverflow is designed for. If you're having a _specific_ problem with a _specific_ piece of code, please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question about just that issue.

Comment: @Photon  The integers are between 2 and
10000, inclusive. The end of the input is indicated by a zero.

Comment: @SeanWerkema Thanks for the information.

Comment: Your questions appear to boil down to "please give me a fast algorithm and the code for it."  This is too broad for SO (Stack Overflow).  As for the code you posted, please note the posting guidelines that suggest you "make it easy for others to help you".  A wall of semantically meaningless variable names and undocumented simple operations does not promote our understanding of what you *did* implement.  This is why I'm not working on improvements to this code.

Answer (score 0):

Well your code times out because you keep recalculating stuff you already know:

1. You're recalculating all primes for each query (you can
   pre-calculate all needed primes before queries start)
2. You're recalculating stuff which you already know. (i.e. if there's
   query that asks to count representations for some integer x, and
   then later some other query also asks same thing do you really need to calculate the answer again?)

Suggestions:

1. There's only 10000 possible queries so just create array
   answer[10001] and fill with all possible answers.
2. 10000 is not much so you can even save all answers in file and
   hard-code it as an array in code, so all queries will be answered in
   O(1) per query

Comment: I just tried that way.First, all primes between 2 and 10000 were stored in a array.Then I calculated the answer.But I think I have problem in EOF, in fourth line of this program.Was my syntax wrong about EOF?

Comment: You don't need to check for EOF, you mentioned that input is terminated by 0 so just do something like while(1) { read n, if n is 0 break}.

Comment: But requirement for submitting solution need EOF.I use nested while loop to express EOF then termination with zero.But after that Time Limit Exceeded.